# Perl script to ssh fron Node_A to many Nodes and find specific logs and scp them back over to Node A

Tags: perl

Running into the following problem on my perl script, I'm trying to ssh to a host, find specific logs, and scp them back over.
This fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
############################
use strict;
use warnings;

###Pulling all hosts from a file
my $nodes = '/tmp/all-servers.txt';
open my $handle, '<', $nodes;
chomp (my @HOSTS = <$handle>);
close $handle;

chomp (my $USER  = "user");

### Go through all Nodes, find the logs, and scp them over to Node_A
foreach my $host (@HOSTS) {

my $output = `ssh $USER\@$host  find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name *TEST* | xargs -I{} scp {} $USER\@Node-A:/home/LOGS`;

}
```

The SCP FAILS, I'm assuming it fails because the data from the scalar is still in memory?

Comment: What is scp's error message?

Comment: I modified it and used Choroba's approach:  my $status = system qq< /usr/bin/ssh $USER\@$host 'find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*TEST*" > . qq< | xargs -I{} scp {} $USER\@Node-A:/home/LOGS' >;
but now I get this:::::::::
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
lost connection
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
lost connection
31488
bash-3.2$
seeems like it found the two files I was looking for but somewhere it failed

Comment: use [Net::OpenSSH::Paralell](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel);

Answer (score 0):

Does it work from the command line? It seems the pipe is not part of the ssh command, so the scp runs from the same server where the Perl script is running - which is in contradiction with what you describe.

Also, you should quote `*TEST*`, as the shell might expand the asterisks by random files appearing in the working directory.

Also, as `scp` doesn't return any reasonable output, I'd go with `system` instead of `` `...` ``.

```
my $status = system qq< ssh $USER\@$host 'find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*TEST*" >
                  . qq< | xargs -I{} scp {} $USER\@Node-A:/home/LOGS' >;
```

Comment: Choroba, I modified it to use `ssh $USER\@$host  'find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name *TEST* | xargs -I{} scp {} $USER\@Node-A:/home/LOGS'`

Comment: Still does not work......seems to find the "TEST" files which are TEST1.txt and TEST2.txt, but when the script ends it I get this back "/tmp/TEST1.txt: Not a directory, /tmp/TEST2.txt: Not a directory"

Comment: @zroz9: Why did you remove the quotes around `*TEST*`? The files will be found in the home directory of the user on the remote machine.

Comment: choroba: Still did not like it

Comment: syntax error at ./test.pl line 30, near "qq< /usr/bin/ssh $USER\@$host 'find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*TEST*" >  qq< | xargs -I{} scp {} $USER\@server1:/tmp/LOGS' >"
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: ok, so now it worked, but for some reason I got this......Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
lost connection
31488
bash-3.2$

Comment: @zroz9: Maybe you don't have passwordless acces from $host back to server1?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, you can't scp data within an array, first you have to put the retrieved data somewhere.  The problem was not "scp", scp was always doing its job, it was the data being retrieved.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
############################
use strict; 
use warnings;

###Pulling all hosts from a file
my $nodes = '/tmp/all-servers.txt';
open my $handle, '<', $nodes;
chomp (my @HOSTS = <$handle>);
close $handle;

chomp (my $USER  = "user");

### Go through all Nodes, find the logs, and scp them over to Node_A
foreach my $host (@HOSTS) {
my @retrieved_files = `ssh $USER\@$host "ls -l /tmp > 2>/dev/null" 2>/dev/null`;
    foreach my $y (@retrieved_files) {
        my @tmpfiles = split (/\s+/,$y);
        my $newfile  = $tmpfiles[0];

        system("/usr/bin/scp $USER\@$host:$tmpfiles[0] /tmp/$newfile");
    }
}
```